# Integrating Navigation of iPhone app and Xpages App

Tags: ios, xpages

I am finishing an iPhone app for my company.

I am using Xcode and Xpages, as we are a Lotus Notes shop.

In Xcode I am using a UINavigation Controller with a Table View for selections. One selection is the Company Directory, which is an Xpage using the Xpages Mobile Controls (Single Page Application and then Application pages, etc.). This works fine EXCEPT for the navigation hand off between the Xcode parts of the app and Xpages. I end up with two sets of navigation controls, which is not good.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figured this out.

It really isn't anything to do with Xpages, but with using UIWebViews within iOS.

The problem was that on the first webView, I wanted to show the iOS Navigation, but in any subsequent ones I didn't want to - would just prefer to use the web navigation.

There is a delegation method in iOS Web views that allows you to show or hide the navigation bar. I added this delegate and just check to see which page I am on. If on the first one, I show the iOS Navigation, else I suppress.

This works great!

Comment: Great! Could you post some sample code snippets of your solution?

Comment: Use the methodshouldStartLoadingWithRequest.
 NSURL *url = request.URL;
 NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];    
    if([urlString isEqual: @"https:yoururl"]
       ||
       [urlString isEqual: @"https:yoururl"]
       )
        {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE animated:YES];
    } else {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:YES];
    }
    return YES;